# Why is my service not updating on my app component?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working with Ionic 4 and I want to show information about the current logged user but is not working I mean it works on any component except the app component, I am using a variable called userData which is a BehaviorSubject. Do you know what is wrong with my code?

auth.service.ts

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, from, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { take, map,tap, switchMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { JwtHelperService } from "@auth0/angular-jwt";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Tokens } from '../models/tokens';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

const helper = new JwtHelperService();
//Agregar token access y refresh
const accessToken = 'access';
const refreshToken = 'refresh';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  public user: Observable<any>;
  private userData = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  private access: string = null;
  private refresh: string = null;
  constructor(private storage: Storage, private http: HttpClient, private plt: Platform, private router: Router) { 
    this.loadStoredTokens();  
  }

  getTokenExpirationDate(userData): Date {
    if (userData['exp'] === undefined) return null;

    const date = new Date(0); 
    date.setUTCSeconds(userData['exp']);
    return date;
  }

  isAcessTokenExpired(): boolean {
    let userData = this.userData.getValue();
    console.log(userData);
    if(!userData) return true;

    const date = this.getTokenExpirationDate(userData);
    if(date === undefined) return false;
    return !(date.valueOf() > new Date().valueOf());
  }

  loadStoredTokens() {
    let platformObs = from(this.plt.ready());

    this.user = platformObs.pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        return from(this.storage.get(refreshToken));
      }),
      map(refreshToken => {
        if (refreshToken) {
          this.refresh = refreshToken;
        } else {
          this.refresh = null;
        }
      }),
      switchMap(() => {
        return from(this.storage.get(accessToken));
      }),
      map(accessToken => {
        if (accessToken) {
          this.access = accessToken;
          let decoded = helper.decodeToken(accessToken); 
          this.userData.next(decoded);
          return true;
        } else {
          this.access = null;
          return null;
        }
      })
    );

  }

  login(credentials: {username: string, password: string }) {
    return this.http
    .post(`${environment.apiUrl}/token/obtain/`,credentials)
    .pipe(
      take(1),
      map(res => {
        // Extract the JWT
        return res;
      }),
      switchMap(token => {
        let decoded = helper.decodeToken(token['access']);
        this.userData.next(decoded);

        from(this.storage.set(refreshToken, token['refresh']))
        let storageObs = from(this.storage.set(accessToken, token['access']));
        return storageObs;
      })
    );

  }

  getUser() {
    return this.userData.getValue();
  }

  logout() {
    this.storage.remove(accessToken).then(() => {

      this.storage.remove(refreshToken).then(() => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        this.userData.next(null);
      });

    });
  }

getAccessToken() {
  return  this.access;
}

 getRefreshToken() {
  return this.refresh;
}

setAccessToken(token) {
  this.storage.set(accessToken, token);
}

  refreshToken() {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/token/refresh/`, {
    'refresh': this.getRefreshToken()
    }).pipe(tap((tokens: Tokens) => {
      this.setAccessToken(tokens.access);
      this.access = tokens.access;
    }));
  }
}
```

app.component.ts (I am using getUser() function in order to get the current user information)

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChildren, QueryList, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform, ModalController, ActionSheetController, PopoverController, IonRouterOutlet, MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { faHome, faInfo, faFileContract } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AuthService } from './auth/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public selectedIndex = 0;
  user = null;

  public appPages = [
    {
      title: 'Home',
      url: '/home',
      icon: faHome
    },
    {
      title: 'About',
      url: '/about',
      icon: faInfo
    },
    {
      title: 'Legal',
      url: '/legal',
      icon: faFileContract
    }
  ];


  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    public modalCtrl: ModalController,
    private menu: MenuController,
    private actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController,
    private popoverCtrl: PopoverController,
    private router: Router,
    public toastController: ToastController,
    private auth: AuthService
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }



  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#D4AF37');
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.user = this.auth.getUser();
    const path = window.location.pathname.split('home/')[1];
    if (path !== undefined) {
      this.selectedIndex = this.appPages.findIndex(page => page.title.toLowerCase() === path.toLowerCase());
    }



  }


}
```

app.component.html (here I want to show the user information, the same code is working in every component except this)

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content">
    <ion-menu contentId="main-content" type="overlay">
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list id="inbox-list">
          <ion-list-header>Menu</ion-list-header>
          <ion-note *ngIf="user">{{ user.email }} </ion-note>

          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages; let i = index">
            <ion-item (click)="selectedIndex = i" routerDirection="root" [routerLink]="[p.url]" lines="none" detail="false" [class.selected]="selectedIndex == i">
              <fa-icon (keyup)="onKeyFaIcon($event)" slot="start" [icon]="p.icon"></fa-icon>

              <ion-label>{{ p.title }}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>

      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

Comment: subscribe to get the values or use async pipe in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the `userData` variable is assigned a new value in functions `loadStoredTokens()` and `login()`. I don't see `login()` function called anywhere and the `loadStoreTokens()` function is wrongfully invoked synchronously. It handles data asynchronously, and the data flow should be asynchronous as well.

Service

```js
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private storage: Storage, private http: HttpClient, private plt: Platform, private router: Router) { 
    this.loadStoredTokens().subscribe(
      accessToken => {
        let decoded = helper.decodeToken(accessToken); 
        this.userData.next(decoded);
      },
    );  
  }

  loadStoredTokens() {
    const result = new Subject<any>();
    let platformObs = from(this.plt.ready());

    this.user = platformObs.pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        return from(this.storage.get(refreshToken));
      }),
      map(refreshToken => {
        if (refreshToken) {
          this.refresh = refreshToken;
        } else {
          this.refresh = null;
        }
      }),
      switchMap(() => {
        return from(this.storage.get(accessToken));
      }),
      map(accessToken => {
        if (accessToken) {
          this.access = accessToken;
          result.next(accessToken);
        } else {
          this.access = null;
          result.next(null);
        }
      })
    );

  return result.asObservable();
}
```

Also if you're using `getValue()` function of `BehaviorSubject` there isn't any use of the multicast observable. Instead you could skip the `getValue()` in the service and subscribe to it in the component.

Service

```js
getUser() {
  return this.userData.asObservable();
}
```

Component

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.auth.getUser().subscribe(
    user => { this.user = user }
  );
}
```

Use safe navigation operator `?.` in the template to check if the `user` variable is defined before trying to access it's properties. Because initially the value is `null` as specified from the default value of the `BehaviorSubject`.

```html
<ion-note *ngIf="user">{{ user?.email }} </ion-note>
```

Or alternatively you could skip the subscription in the component controller and use `async` pipe in the template.

Component

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.user = this.auth.getUser();
}
```

Template

```html
<ion-note *ngIf="user">{{ (user | async)?.email }} </ion-note>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because BehaviorSubject is async and you need to subscribe to it.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.auth.getUser().subscribe(user => this.user = user);
}
```

Also keep in mind that it's not instant and all dependencies on `this.user` should be async too.

For example in template you can check

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="user">
  {{ user }} now we can use it
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use async pipe to achieve this. As the user has no data while app loads. Please follow the code, it might help you.

app.component.html

```
<ion-app>
<ion-split-pane contentId="main-content">
<ion-menu contentId="main-content" type="overlay">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list id="inbox-list">
      <ion-list-header>Menu</ion-list-header>
      <ion-note *ngIf="user">{{ auth?.userData?.email | async }} </ion-note>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
```

> keep the email properties in userData object. And keep AuthService scope as public while injection in the `app.component.ts constructor.`